# Add delete, approve, spam Links to Comments

Tags: comments, links, moderation

Anyone know how to add quick comment moderation links for users who have permission to add/edit posts and comments? (Upprove / Unappove / Edit / Spam / Trash ). **Note:** in my comments.php I call the loop with `<?php wp_list_comments(); ?>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per default `wp_list_comments()` calls the class `Walker_Comment`. Its method `start_el()` calls `edit_comment_link()` and here we find a filter for your question: It is called `'edit_comment_link'` and it passes two variables, the link text and the comment ID, which we can use.

The URLs to mark a comment as spam or to delete it are:

- `wp-admin/comment.php?c=1&action=cdc&dt=spam` for spam, and
- `wp-admin/comment.php?c=1&action=cdc` for deletion.

We can add a parameter `redirect_to=` to send us back to the post after the comment was trashed.

Here is a sample plugin I just hacked together ([GitHub address](https://gist.github.com/2866124)):

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: T5 Comment moderation links
 * Version:     2012.06.04
 * Author:      Thomas Scholz <info@toscho.de>
 * Author URI:  http://toscho.de
 * License:     MIT
 * License URI: http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 */

if ( ! function_exists( 't5_comment_mod_links' ) )
{
    add_filter( 'edit_comment_link', 't5_comment_mod_links', 10, 2 );

    /**
     * Adds Spam and Delete links to the Sdit link.
     *
     * @wp-hook edit_comment_link
     * @param   string  $link Edit link markup
     * @param   int $id Comment ID
     * @return  string
     */
    function t5_comment_mod_links( $link, $id )
    {
        $template = ' <a class="comment-edit-link" href="%1$s%2$s">%3$s</a>';
        $admin_url = admin_url( "comment.php?c=$id&action=" );

        // Mark as Spam.
        $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc&dt=spam', __( 'Spam' ) );
        // Delete.
        $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc', __( 'Delete' ) );

        // Approve or unapprove.
        $comment = get_comment( $id );

        if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved )
        {
            $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'approvecomment', __( 'Approve' ) );
        }
        else
        {
            $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'unapprovecomment', __( 'Unapprove' ) );
        }

        return $link;
    }
}
```

Screenshot with TwentyEleven (order reversed by the stylesheet):

[image]

Comment: Great piece of code. Is there a way to add the *approve* link as well?

Comment: @davebowker See my update.

Comment: Magic. Cheers, toscho!

Comment: @toscho the Approve and Unapproved link actually dont work. It redirect to "Are you really want to do this" page. Will you please fix the issue and update the code?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use (added as a reference — toscho's answer IS BETTER for many reasons):

```
<?php if (current_user_can('edit_post')) {
    $id = get_comment_ID();
    echo ' <a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&c=$id").'">[Delete]</a>';
    echo ' <a href="'.admin_url("comment.php?action=cdc&dt=spam&c=$id").'">[Spam]</a>';
} ?>
```

Most themes already come with an "Edit" link, so I didn't include that.

**Example Preview:**

[image: Delete Spam]

Answer (score 0):

In 2022, unfortunately, the [accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/54122/223620) does no longer work... without some changes, at least. You now need to add a nonce or the action will be rejected as per protocol. But this can be amended:

```
$template = '<a class="comment-spam-link" href="%1$s">%2$s</a>';
$admin_url = admin_url( 'comment.php?c=' . $comment_id . '&action=' );
$nonce_url = esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $admin_url . 'spamcomment', 'delete-comment_' . $comment_id ) );

// $nonce_url = esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $admin_url . 'trashcomment', 'delete-comment_' . $comment_id ) );
// $nonce_url = esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $admin_url . 'approvecomment', 'approve-comment_' . $comment_id ) );
// $nonce_url = esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $admin_url . 'unapprovecomment', 'approve-comment_' . $comment_id ) );
// $nonce_url = esc_url( wp_nonce_url( $admin_url . 'deletecomment', 'delete-comment_' . $comment_id ) );
```

And used like this, for example, although I strongly recommend adding `&redirect_to=` as well:

```
$output = sprintf( $template, $nonce_url, __( 'Spam' ) );
```

Taken from the core [wp-admin/comment.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/comment.php).