# How to add delete, approve, spam Links to Comments

Tags: php, plugin-development, comments

I am developing a plugin where I list all the available comments and then I want to have a links like Delete, Approve, Unapprove or Spam etc.

I have followed a thread here: [Add delete, approve, spam Links to Comments](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54116/add-delete-approve-spam-links-to-comments). But while approving I get the error saying The link you followed has expired and I can't comment in that thread.

Can anyone please assist?

Below is my code:

```
$template = ' <a class="comment-edit-link" href="%1$s%2$s">%3$s</a>';
$admin_url = admin_url( "comment.php?c=$comment->comment_ID&action=" );
$link = '';
                            // Mark as Spam.
$link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc&dt=spam', __( 'Spam' ) );
                            // Delete.
$link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'cdc', __( 'Delete' ) );
// Approve or unapprove.                             

if ( '0' === $comment->comment_approved )
{
   $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'approvecomment', __( 'Approve' ) );
}
else
{
  $link .= sprintf( $template, $admin_url, 'unapprovecomment', __( 'Unapprove' ) );
}
echo $link;
```

Comment: Shouldn’t there be some nonce in that url?

Comment: look the code here to see how are constructed the URL https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.6/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-comments-list-table.php#L510